# Facing issue with Mixed content in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jsp

**Mixed Content:** The site at 'https://abcbank.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://abcbank.com/APP/ShowQueryDumpDialog.jsp?contentType=xls&fileName=QDTestFile_1626859643360.xls' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

Server is running on https connection only and redirection URL also https.

Please let us know what should I change JSP code or Javascript Code to allow the file to download.

Comment: The error message basically already tells you all that you need to know. There must be a redirect taking place that uses http instead of https.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Thanks for the reply. Here we are redirecting to https URL only. But, still we are getting this issue.